# Listview not clickable when the textview inside that listview is selectable

Tags: android, listview, onclick, click

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Log.d("test1","run");
    }
});
```

The listview is not fire , if I set like this:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
```

After I remove the textIsSelectable, the onitemclicklistener is fired.

I have studied a while, and I followed some suggestion on the internet

e.g.

put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to parent view

The clicklistener is fired this time , but when select the text it show error:

```
TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.
```

Can both function exist? thanks a lot

Comment: can you post more info about your code ? like , where did you place this TextView ? did you create the adapter ?

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to select some part of text which is in a `ListView` . If I'm correct, why not change your app design? Leave *onItemClickListener* and when an item is clicked, open a popup when user can select the desired text.

Answer (score 1):

You can add manually `OnClickListener` to your parent in list adapter. Dont forget to delete `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`. I just tried it.

```
viewHolder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code,remove

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

It may solve your problem.

```
viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener
(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```